# What's wrong with this sed expression?

Tags: sed

```
$ echo "104_Fri" | sed 's/^\([0-9]+\)_\([A-Za-z]+\)$/\1;\2/'
104_Fri
```

I would like to match the digits at the beginning and the letters at the end - each as a group. Afterwards I want to output the first group, a semicolon and then the second group.

I would expect this expression to yield:

```
104;Fri
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must escape plus symbol `+`, too:

```
$ echo "104_Fri" | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)_\([A-Za-z]\+\)$/\1;\2/'
104;Fri
```

Answer (score 11):

Backslash the `+`:

```
$ echo "104_Fri" | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)_\([A-Za-z]\+\)$/\1;\2/'
104;Fri
```

Note that [`+` is not a standard basic regular expression metacharacter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03), and so doesn't have portable behaviour in `sed` even when backslashed.

You should use `sed -r` or `sed -E` to enable [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) instead, in which you don't need to backslash any of these characters. These options are also non-standard, but at least you'll get an error if they're unsupported rather than mysterious failures. The options are supported by [GNU `sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) and all the main BSD derivatives ([FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sed.1), [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sed+1+NetBSD-current), [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)), but not in many of the commercial Unix versions.

If you need extended regular expressions truly portably, use [`awk`, which always uses them](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04).

Comment: Of course, `x+` is easily rewritten as `xx*` if the portable subset of `sed` must be used.

Comment: TIL why ab+ doesn't work in vim while ab* does!

Comment: If everyone used PCRE (or a subset of it, such as POSIX ERE), the world would be a happier place.

Answer (score 6):

Add the `-r` option ;-) for extended regexps, and the need to `\` active content diminishes.

```
$ echo "104_Fri" | sed -re 's/^([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+)$/\1;\2/'
104;Fri
```

As the Q is written, (no background data) the splitting-task could be done in several other simpler ways:

```
$ echo "104_Fri" | tr '_' ';'
104;Fri

$ echo "104_Fri" | sed  's/_/;/'
104;Fri
```

... to name two.

Answer (score 5):

You might also alternate addresses. You wind up using far fewer crazy backslashes that way.

```
sed -n '/._./{/^[0-9]*.[A-Za-z]*$/s/_/;/p;}'

sed -n '/[^0-9].*_.*[^A-Za-z]/d;/._./s/_/;/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Perl instead, as it comes preinstalled on most Unix systems:

```
$ echo '104_Fri' | perl -p -e 's/^([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+)$/$1;$2/'
```

You can simplify that further:

```
$ echo '104_Fri' | perl -p -e 's/^(\d+)_([a-z]+)$/$1;$2/i'
```

---

**Note:** If your input is really as simple as in the question, a simple `tr` will do:

```
$ echo '104_Fri' | tr '_' ';'
```

Or with Perl:

```
$ echo '104_Fri' | perl -p -e 's/_/;/'
```